# Java Arrays/Loops

Tags: java, arrays

Hi i saw this question online and i was trying to solve it but i just could not understand how the answered was determined.

```
int[] n = {0, 1, 0, -1};

for (int i = 1; i < n.length; i++) {
    if (n[i] == 0 && n[i - 1] != 0) {
        int x = n[i - 1];
        n[i - 1] = n[i];
        n[i] = x;               
    }        
}
System.out.println(n[2]);
```

The answer is 1 which i have no idea how or why is it 1. Wonder if anyone is kind enough to explain why is the answer 1.

Comment: What did you expect it to be?

Comment: It's swapping elements if the element is zero but the preceding element is non-zero. As such, the only elements which get swapped are when `i == 2`.

Comment: i expected it would be 0 instead of 1

Comment: For this, debugging or even better if you are new, a sheet of paper !

Comment: Thank you i understand now... i feel so dumb @AxelH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block inside the `if` swaps the two numbers in `n[i]` and `n[i - 1]`.

The `if` itself (The condition) checks if the `n[i]` is zero and `n[i - 1]` is non-zero.

The loop runs over all `i` values from 1 to the end of the array.

Let's follow the loop run, shall we? (row numbers are `i` value)

1. `n[1]` is 1, `n[0]` is 0 - condition false and `if` block not entered.
2. `n[2]` is 0, `n[1]` is 1 - condition true and `if` block entered. Now `n[2]` is 1, `n[1]` is 0.
3. `n[3]` is -1, `n[2]` is 1 - condition false and `if` block not entered.

End of array.

So `n[2]` is 1.

Comment: I would add the array value on each iteration to be even more visual. (like a debugger with a breakpoint on the loop). Good explication

Comment: Thank you for a proper explanation i understand the logic behind it now

Answer (score 0):

Array starts from 0. So n[2] means third element after the swap.

After swap: {0, 0, 1, -1}
So n[2]=1.

Answer (score 0):

It´s pretty simple:

- You have a list of 4 elements
- You go through the list but start with the second element as indexes start with 0
- As you don´t go into the if condition at the first time you go into the loop at second time and this time you get into the if condition.
- n[i] is now 1 and n[i-1] is currently 0
- The elements get swapped so n[i] is 0 and n[i-1] is 1
- Therefore the answer is 1

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (n[i] == 0 && n[i - 1] != 0) {
        //Swapping elements i and  i - 1
        int x = n[i - 1];
        n[i - 1] = n[i];
        n[i] = x;
```

The only time when the condition is true occurs when i = 2.
Therefore n[2] = n[1] = 1;